# How to update database from code first

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I added a new row to the table from code view like this:

```
Users = new List<User>(){
new User(){Name = "Sata", LastName = "XXXX"},
new User(){Name = "John", LastName = "YYYYY"},
},
```

So the new row is `{Name = "John", LastName = "YYYYY"},`

How to update the database to include the above mentioned row as well.

I do `update-database`  but it does not find any changes to update the database.

Is there some different command to update the date tables rows?

Answer (score 1):

Override the Seed() method on the Configuration class which runs regardless of database changes to do that. Then you could use your context to do an AddOrUpdate on the collection. This requires a key field. If you don't have a key field you could just test for existance (if !context.Users.Any() ...)

```
    context.Users.AddOrUpdate(
        p => p.UniqueField,
        new User { Name = "Sata", LastName = "XXXX" },
        new User { Name = "John", LastName = "YYYYY" }
    );
```

See http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application